# How to submit POST request to '"current_url"/submit' in HTML's form action using Django templates?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, forms

Let's say I have many posts and each post has a url `example.com/post_id`. Also there is a HTML form after this post where one can submit comment. If I had to submit this comment to this url: `example.com/submit` , then I could just do `<form action="submit/" method="post">`. But, I want this comment to be submitted to this url: `example.com/post_id/submit` so that when it's view is called, that view *has access to `post_id`*. This is so I can store the entered comment along with `post_id` in the database. (I can access the request url in view by `request.path_info`.)

One approach would be to pass `{{request.path}}` concatenated with "submit" in the HTML form action in the template. But I am not able to do that. One can do `{{value|add:"submit"}}`. But how do I put `{{request.path}}` in place of value?

tl;dr Using django templates, how to I pass `post_id/submit` url to HTML form action. (Here current url is `example.com/post_id`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bad idea to try and parse/modify the existing URL. But there's no reason to. Your template presumably already has access to the post itself, so you should use this to construct the URL via the normal `{% url %}` tag.

```
<form action="{% url "submit_comment" post_id=post.id %}" method="POST">
```

assuming the post is passed to the template as `post` and there is a urlconf that looks like this:

```
url(r'(?P<post_id>\d+)/submit/$', views.submit_comment, name='submit_comment'),
```

Comment: Hey, I am not able to make it work. Can you please explain how `"{% url ... %}"` works?